# Python: Resize Image to a fixed size, ignoring the initial aspect ratio

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, resize-image

I am trying to scale an incoming image which can be of (any type, any size) to a fixed grayscale image (eg 14x14). What I do is:

```
from PIL import Image
...
img = Image.open(args.picture).convert('L')
img.thumbnail( (14,14), Image.ANTIALIAS)   #img.resize returns Non-Type
```

but this returns a 12x14 instead of 14x14, due to the original aspect ratio apparently.

How would I achieve a 14x14, for any possible input?

Comment: How do you want to achieve that aspect ratio? Do you want to crop? Have black borders? Squish to fit?

Comment: Squish to fit, or let's say, fill the remaining rows/cols with zeros

Comment: silly question, resize works actually... I was doing something wrong apparently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `thumbnail` entry from the [PIL docs](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) specifically says it maintains the aspect ratio of the original.  Try using `resize` instead, it doesn't appear to maintain aspect ratio, at least from what I see.